# VBA define ranges and static date stamps

Tags: vba, excel

I need some help with this code as it doesn't work properly.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In Target
    With Cell
    If .Column = Range("W:W").Column Then
    Cells(.Row, "AC").Value = Int(Now)
    End If
    End With
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

I am trying to get automatic static date stamps in column "AC" every time I fill in cells in column "W" and I want to start with row "19".
Tried to use

```
If .Column = Range("W19").End(xldown) Then
```

but it doesn't work.

I've just started using macro and vba and it will really help me if you can explain any solutions to me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always turn off events if you are going to write to the worksheet in order that the [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro does not try to run on top of itself.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("W:W")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim rng As Range
        For Each rng In Intersect(Target, Columns("W:W"))
            If rng.Row > 18 Then _
                rng.Offset(0, 6) = Date 'or Now for datetime
        Next rng
    End If
bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This should handle multiple changes to column W like a block range paste.